# How to change my data frame format? From wide format to long format?

Tags: r

My df is like this

```
df <- data.frame(id1 = c(1,1,1),
                   v = c("a","b","c"),
                   id2 = c(2,2,2), 
                   v = c("d","e","f"))
```

and I want id to be something like this

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
                 v = c("a","b","c", "d","e","f"))
```

My acctural variable name is something like V1, V2....V50, is that possible to do that ?

THank you

Comment: This is a typical reshape wide to long - `reshape(df, direction="long", varying=TRUE, sep="")` would do it if you had id1, id2 etc and v1, v2 etc variables.

Comment: See `dplyr::pivot_longer()` and `reshape()` functions. There are tens or even hundreds of questions about them.

Comment: By the way the df declaration is invalid as there is a duplicate column `v`